# Cropping an image as a 3d array

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, tensorflow

I have a `tensor` of dimension `(224, 224, 3)` representing an image. I would like to firstly "crop" this image using bounding box dimensions in the format `bndbox = [x1, y1, x2, y2]` and then resize this cropped image back to a dimension of `(224, 224, 3)`.

Is there a simple way of doing this with numpy/cv2(OpenCV)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing that your tensor supports slicing, simply select the bounding box, then you can resize with `cv2.resize`:

```
cv2.resize(img[y1:y2,x1:x2], (224, 224))
```

Just note that `img` is probably selected in height then in width, while the shape argument for `cv2.resize` takes (width, height).